# Creating buffer based on attribute in row using GeoPandas

Tags: python, fields-attributes, buffer, geopandas, polygon-creation

I have the following `DataFrame` converted into `GeoDataFrame`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

data = {
    'lat':[-34.661412, -38.700402],
    'lng':[-58.366424, -62.294023],
    'buffer_value':[1000000000000,100000000000]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(far.lng, far.lat))
```

I want to create a buffer based on `"buffer_value"` distance which is different for each column.

Using:

```py
gdf['buffer_0'] = gdf.buffer(10, resolution=16)
```

creates the same distance buffer for all rows, and not different buffers for each row.

I tried the following two different alternatives:

```py
gdf['buffer_1'] = gdf.apply(lambda row: row.geometry.buffer(row.buffer_value, resolution=16), axis=1)
```

and

```
def buffer(row):
    return row.geometry.buffer(row.buffer_value)

gdf['buffer_2'] = gdf.apply(buffer, axis=1)
```

But both alternatives create an object column, not a geometry column.

```
<class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype   
---  ------        --------------  -----   
 0   lat           2 non-null      float64 
 1   lng           2 non-null      float64 
 2   buffer_value  2 non-null      int64   
 3   geometry      2 non-null      geometry
 4   buffer_1      2 non-null      object  
 5   buffer_2      2 non-null      object  
 6   buffer_0      2 non-null      geometry
dtypes: float64(2), geometry(2), int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 240.0+ bytes
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

# dataframe
data = {
    'lat':[-34.661412, -38.700402],
    'lng':[-58.366424, -62.294023],
    'buffer_value':[1000000000000,100000000000]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df['lng'], df['lat']))

# buffering
gdf['buffer'] = gdf.buffer(gdf['buffer_value'], resolution=16)

# show data
gdf.head()
gdf.dtypes
gdf['buffer'].plot(facecolor="none", edgecolor="black")
```

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer. `buffer` is a vectorized function and using `apply` or loop will have a significant impact on performance.

Comment: Works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the custom function below called `make_variable_buffer`. Here is a small reproducible example.

```py
import geopandas as gpd

def make_variable_buffer(input_df, 
                         buffer_size_col_name, 
                         geometry_column_name='geometry'):
    '''
    Creates a new GeoDataFrame whose geometries are the result of generating 
    variable-sized buffers from the input geometries. 
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    input_df : gpd.GeoDataFrame
        Input dataframe. The function will generate a copy of this dataframe 
        and the geometry of each row of this new dataframe will be a buffered 
        version of the geometries in the input dataframe
    buffer_size_col_name : str
        Name of the column of the input_df that contains the sizes/magnitudes 
        of the variable buffer. Please note that this measure is in the same 
        unit as your input features' CRS. 
    geometry_column_name : str
        Name of the column of the input_df that contains the geometries
        The default is 'geometry'.

    Returns
    -------
    buff_df : gpd.GeoDataFrame
        Dataframe that contains the buffers of varying sizes.

    '''
    
    # Copying the input_df
    buff_df = input_df.copy()
    
    # Creating the varying-sized buffer
    buff_df['geometry'] = input_df.apply(lambda row: 
                                        (row[geometry_column_name]
                                         .buffer(row[buffer_size_col_name])),
                                        axis=1)
    
    # Returning the newly-created dataframe
    return buff_df

data = {'lat':[-34.661412, -38.700402],
        'lng':[-58.366424, -62.294023],
        'buffer_value':[1,0.3]}

df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data, 
                      geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(data['lng'], 
                                                  data['lat']), 
                      crs='epsg:4326')



buff_df = make_variable_buffer(input_df=df, 
                               buffer_size_col_name='buffer_value',
                               geometry_column_name='geometry')

buff_df.plot()
```

This yields two different buffer sizes:

[image: varying buffer sizes]