# How to create variable distance buffers around polygons in Python

Tags: python, gdal, polygon, buffer, ogr

I have a shapefile of polygons and I would like to create buffers around the edges of each polygon. However, rather than use a single buffer distance for all of the polygons, I am trying to find a way to create variable distance buffers. Specifically, within the attribute table for this layer, I have a column of `Distances` where each polygon has assigned to it its own unique distance. I want to create buffers around each polygon that use each polygon's unique distance value as its unique buffer distance.

I have found so far from "Python GDAL/OGR Cookbook 1.0 documentation" (linked here: http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html?highlight=buffer) is that I can use the following to create buffers:

```
createBuffer(inputfn, outputBufferfn, bufferDist):
```

However, this entails using the same buffer distance for each polygon. What I am trying to figure out specifically is, how can I use this `createBuffer()` function (or another function if this one is not appropriate here) to use my `Distances` column to provide a unique buffer distance for each polygon?

Comment: On the cookbook page you linked, it defines the buffer function.  I would modify that function for your case.  Remove bufferDist parameter.  Then, in the for feature in inputLyr:... loop, add something like bufferDist = feature.getField("Distances").

Answer (score 6):

Modified version of `createBuffer` function using a column as the distance value is here:

```py
import ogr, os

def createBuffer(inputfn, outputBufferfn, bufferField):
    inputds = ogr.Open(inputfn)
    inputlyr = inputds.GetLayer()

    shpdriver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
    if os.path.exists(outputBufferfn):
        shpdriver.DeleteDataSource(outputBufferfn)

    outputBufferds = shpdriver.CreateDataSource(outputBufferfn)
    bufferlyr = outputBufferds.CreateLayer(outputBufferfn, geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon)
    featureDefn = bufferlyr.GetLayerDefn()

    for feature in inputlyr:
        ingeom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
        bufferValue = feature.GetField(bufferField)
        geomBuffer = ingeom.Buffer(bufferValue)

        outFeature = ogr.Feature(featureDefn)
        outFeature.SetGeometry(geomBuffer)
        bufferlyr.CreateFeature(outFeature)
        outFeature = None

inputfn = 'input.shp'
outputBufferfn = 'output.shp'
bufferField = 'Distances'

createBuffer(inputfn, outputBufferfn, bufferField)
```

Comment: I am testing this out now, and the function itself is created fine. However, when I enter `inputfn = 'input.shp'', 'outputBufferfn = 'out.shp', 'bufferField = 'Distances'', 'createBuffer(inputfn, outputBufferfn, bufferField)' I get the following error: `RuntimeError: not a string`. I checked an `Distances` is listed as `float64` via `inputfn.dtypes`. Could this mean that there is still something wrong with the column I am referencing for `bufferField`? Also, rather than using `input.shp` for `inputfn` I am just referencing a geopandas dataframe.

Comment: When I do use 'inputfn = 'input.shp'' I get the error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CreateLayer'`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`GeoPandas`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started.html) library to read in your Shapefile as a `GeoDataFrame`.

Then you can make use of the `GeoDataFrame`'s vectorized `buffer` function, as suggested in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/398546/123828) by [Encomium](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/60748/encomium).

Here's a quick mock-up of what it would look like.

```py
import geopandas as gpd

# Reading in the input shapefile.
input_df = gpd.read_file('path/to/my_shapefile.shp')

# Reading the input CRS. 
input_crs = input_df.crs

# Reprojecting the data. If needed, substitute "WXYZ" with 
# relevant EPSG code. Learn more here: https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/
# Comment out if unnecessary for your specific case.
input_df = input_df.to_crs('epsg:WXYZ')

# Creating the variable-sized buffer
input_df['buffer'] = input_df.buffer(input_df['Distances'])

# Dropping the original geometry and setting the new geometry
buff_df = input_df.drop(columns=['geometry']).set_geometry('buffer')

# Reprojecting the buffered data back to the CRS used in 
# the original input shapefile
buff_df = buff_df.to_crs(input_crs)

# Exporting the output to a shapefile
buff_df.to_file('path/to/buffered_output.shp')
```

This will yield a new shapefile with the same number of rows/features, but each one will be buffered using the value from the `Distances` column.

#### Important note: Mind the CRS!

GeoPandas does not know how to measure distances across different projection/coordinate systems. Therefore, you should pay close attention to the compatibility between the CRS system being used in your input shapefile and the distance units being used in your `Distances` column. Stated clearly, you need to make sure that both the CRS and the `Distances` column have the same units.

For example, if the input shapefile has coordinates coded in WGS84/EPSG4326 (i.e., decimal degree coordinates on an ellipsoid), and your `Distances` column has values in some real-world length unit (for example, feet), the results will not look like you expect. You first will need to convert the data from the input shapefile into a projected CRS.

Thankfully, this is quite easy in `GeoPandas`. You can just use `input_df = input_df.to_crs('epsg:WXYZ')`, where you replace the `WXYZ` with the EPSG code of a projected CRS that works for your specific case. You can learn more about EPSG codes [here](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/) and [here](https://epsg.io/).

### Edit

My original answer used a less efficient method. The current answer uses a vectorized approach suggested [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/398546/123828) by [@Encomium](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/60748/encomium).

Comment: Links might go away. I think you should include (with attribution) the definition of the `make_variable_buffer` function in this answer

Comment: Good point! Thanks! I've added the definition to the body of the main answer. Also, the attribution is easy: I'm the one who wrote the other answer too! Hahahaha...

Comment: Actually, scratch that. Looking at the original question I linked to, I found an even better approach. I've edited my answer and given the proper attribution to the original solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is something where SQL queries work nicely. Haven't tested it but this might be close to what you want:
`select *, st_Buffer(geometry, my_vect.Distance) from my_vect`

You can do this using `ogr2ogr` on the command line:

```
ogr2ogr \
     -sql "select *, ST_Buffer(geometry, my_vect.Distance) from my_vect" `\
     -dialect SQLite output_vect.shp my_vect.shp
```

If you want to use it from within Python, `gdal.VectorTranslate` will allow you to translate (sorry! ;-D) the previous shell command to a Python command.

Note that Distance needs to be in the same units as the CRS of the geometry you are expanding, but you can read more about this [on the documentation](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html#p14)